# Inherit a class in JUnit - is it a good practise?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have this problem. One class (and actually with one public method) to test, and ~30 test scenarios stored in the separate xml files. As one unit test class would be too long (need to test all the files in separate test), I decided to divide them into few groups (few classes), and now the questions occur.

The unit test itself implements few other methods, used in testing (for getting resources, formatting calendar in different matter), as I got few of those unit classes I should also copy those methods.

I just thought if I could create additional class for the methods, and use simply inheritance, or maybe I should create each unit test with the those copied methods? What is the good practice in such a case?

Comment: Copying code is almost always a bad idea. I've always been happy to use inheritance in this situation, although some people dislike it. In general prefer delegation to inheritance - could you have a helper class instead of a base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to inheritance is delegation, as mentioned by Alan Stokes. A good way to make use of this in junit is: [use Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules). Some are provided, but you can rather easy create your own set of rules.

The major benefit we have experienced is that you can cherry pick the common features you want to have. Sometimes you just want a tiny bit of the common abstract test class. But as you can only have the full set or nothing, you may end up setting up a database state for a rather simple unit test.

---

In the sample below from the junit Wiki the `TemporaryFolder` Rule adds the ability to the test to create temporary folders and files. Those will be deleted after every test execution.

```java
public static class HasTempFolder {
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
    File createdFile = folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
    File createdFolder = folder.newFolder("subfolder");
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

Another good thing about it is that you can change the behaviour to class level rather easy. A situation where you might want to have this is the setup of an expensive fixture state in a database or search index. Or when you create a big sample XML for some ETL process for which you want to run an integration test. This should be used only when performing read only operations.

To move it to class level, you just need to make the member `static` and add the `@ClassRule` annotation instead of `@Rule`

```java
public static class HasDataBaseState {
  @ClassRule
  public static DataBaseState dbState = new DataBaseState();

  @Test
  public void testUsingDataBaseState() throws IOException {
    // perform tests
    dbState.query("select count from table where attribute = 'x'");
  }
}
```

---

There are more features, but those are covered rather good on the junit wiki. The facts I pointed out are the ones we like most about it.

Answer (score 4):

If you need common test fixtures for a number of different test cases, it's perfectly fine to use an abstract base class for your unit tests. For example, small-scale integration tests using Spring will often use a base class that sets up the test runner and context and then add the specific components they're testing.